# CSS Position model link % up from bottom of image inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not very good with CSS :(

So I have a bootstrap carousel, which obviously has images in it. I've added a div below the image, that contains a link, which opens up a modal with more info. The images resize according the size of the window, currently, my modal link is a fixed position from the bottom, so if the window is small enough, the modal link is way to high up. I need to make it a variable/percentage amount from the bottom or top of the image. Code is below.

```
<div id="our-story-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="/img/bg/history-2007.jpg">
            <div class="more-link">
                <div class="more-modal-link">
                    <a class="" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#our-story-modal-1">More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/img/bg/history-2008.jpg">
            <div class="more-link">
                <div class="more-modal-link">
                    <a class="" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#our-story-modal-1">More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/img/bg/history-2009.jpg">
            <div class="more-link">
                <div class="more-modal-link">
                    <a class="" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#our-story-modal-1">More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#our-story-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#our-story-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>

.our-story-item-image img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.more-link {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    top: -255px;
    background: #a29061;
    height: 72px;
    width: 72px;
    -moz-border-radius: 41px;
    border-radius: 41px;
}

.more-modal-link {
    padding-top: 27px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.more-modal-link a {
    border-top: 1px solid #331a00;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #331a00;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #331a00;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll want to redo the CSS so you're not using things like `top: -#px` but something else instead like `margin: #px/#% auto`.

Comment: I tried margin, but it didn't move the div at all, padding too.

Comment: Set `display:block` on the selectors you need and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

so if it's caused of window size, try to use `@media screen and (min-width: px)` then set the element